# is it possible to read contents of a div from another html using jquery?

Tags: jquery

im trying to read the contents of myDiv which resides in a separate html file and do some appending in the current page,is this possible? i know there is load(), but it displays the whole html as it is.

```
$( ".myDiv" ).each(function(){

//do stuff

});
```

i have tried $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container') route, but it loads the contents from #container in to the div with id #result.i want to read the contents of the div with id #container from ajax/test.html,make some changes then display it in the div with id #result... im trying to use the each function on a div that resides on another page,hope im making some sense

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "and do some appending" part?

Comment: @nick im trying to read the contents from  multiple divs in another page and then build a <ul> list from the contents i have read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.load()` can also load `page fragments`. Example call from the docs:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

would just load the `div` with the id `#container` out of the `test.html` file, into the `div` with the id `#result`.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

**update**

To load & modify the content you need the underlaying `.ajax()` method, like

```
$.ajax({
   url:      'yourfile.html',
   type:     'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
   success:  function(data){
        var $content = $(data).find('.myDIV');
        if($content.length){
           $content.find('p').text('modified');

           $('#some_local_id').append($content);
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks 4 ur answer, i know it will load into the div with id result,i dont want to load it ,i just want to read the contents make some changes and then display it

Comment: Cool I didnt know you could do that! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use load on a non displayed element.

something like this (untested, although I did something like this once)

```
var a = document.createElement("div");
$(a).load("otherpage.html");
```

Then you can do whatever you want to the loaded html.